# Perform an operation on all pairs of rows in a column

Tags: python, pandas

Assume the following DataFrame:

```
id    A   
1     0
2     10
3     200
4     3000
```

I would like to make a calculation betweeen all rows to all other rows.
For example, if the calculation were `lambda r1, r2: abs(r1-r2)`, then the output would be (in some order)

```
id       col_name
1        10
2        200
3        3000
4        190
5        2990
6        2800
```

**Questions:**

1. How to get only the above output?
2. How to associate a result to its creators in the most "pandas like" way?

I would like to keep everything in a single table as much as possible, in a way that still supports reasonable lookup.

The size of my data is not large, and never will be.

---

EDIT1:

One way that would answer my question 2 would be

```
id       col_name    origin1    origin2
1        10          1          2
2        200         1          3
3        3000        1          4
4        190         2          3
5        2990        2          4
6        2800        3          4
```

And I would like to know if this is standard, and has a built in way of doing this, or if there is another/better way

Comment: I don't think pandas has something like that. But you can use numpy's broadcasting: `df.A.values[:,None] - df.A.values`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC `itertools`

```
import itertools

s=list(itertools.combinations(df.index, 2)) 
pd.Series([df.A.loc[x[1]]-df.A.loc[x[0]] for x in s ])
Out[495]: 
0      10
1     200
2    3000
3     190
4    2990
5    2800
dtype: int64
```

Update

```
s=list(itertools.combinations(df.index, 2)) 

pd.DataFrame([x+(df.A.loc[x[1]]-df.A.loc[x[0]],) for x in s ])
Out[518]: 
   0  1     2
0  0  1    10
1  0  2   200
2  0  3  3000
3  1  2   190
4  1  3  2990
5  2  3  2800
```

Comment: @cs95 change to another :-)

Comment: See my edit please for a clarification for question 2

Comment: Please see edit for method 2. Is any one better/more standard than the other? is there another way which would be better?

Comment: why is `list()` required on `itertools.combinations`?

Comment: @Gulzar that is unpack the itertools object to list, Or you can remove it

Comment: This isn't exactly what I need, because the `0` and `1` "origin" indexes point to non existing points (0). How can I force the indexes to come from the original index, and not from a calculation?

Comment: Assume the original index could be non-numeric, and not easily calculatable

Comment: Well, this isn't exactly what I wanted, but it is very readable, and I managed to get what I wanted using this. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Use broadcasted subtraction, then `np.tril_indices` to extract the lower diagonal (positive values).

```
# <= 0.23 
# u = df['A'].values
# 0.24+
u = df['A'].to_numpy()  
u2 = (u[:,None] - u)   

pd.Series(u2[np.tril_indices_from(u2, k=-1)])

0      10
1     200
2     190
3    3000
4    2990
5    2800
dtype: int64
```

Or, use `subtract.outer` to avoid the conversion to array beforehand.

```
u2 = np.subtract.outer(*[df.A]*2)
pd.Series(u2[np.tril_indices_from(u2, k=-1)])
```

If you need the index as well, use

```
idx = np.tril_indices_from(u2, k=-1)
pd.DataFrame({
    'val':u2[np.tril_indices_from(u2, k=-1)], 
    'row': idx[0], 
    'col': idx[1]
})

    val  row  col
0    10    1    0
1   200    2    0
2   190    2    1
3  3000    3    0
4  2990    3    1
5  2800    3    2
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! What is the convention for still keeping track of the origin of the data? Adding a column and duplicating rows? adding columns for "orignin1" and "origin2"? other method?

Comment: @Gulzar I don't understand your question, do you mean keep track of the original index? In that case, I've edited.

Comment: @Gulzar Done . . .

Comment: Is this the standard way of doing something like this? It seems kind of hackey to me, because if the function gets more complex, a large number of columns starts to get added. Seems strange to me that there is nothing built in to handle such cases.

My real use case is calculating all distances between a list of 3d points [given as 6 columns as input]

Comment: @Gulzar Yeah sorry, I can tell you doing all-to-all is something that is more suited to Numpy, not pandas, which is why my answer is exclusively Numpy.

Comment: @Gulzar I should also probably mention this is very fast (faster than anything pandas would do), and there is nothing "hacky" about it.

Comment: Please see edit for method 2. Is any one better/more standard than the other?

Comment: about all to all operations in numpy - I wonder what happens when the dataframe gets too large for memory (not my case, but just in general). Is there really no good way supported in pandas?

Comment: @Gulzar iterative edits and debugging is discouraged here, but to answer your question just use df.index.repeat(range(4)) for that index. And for the Nth time, this is an esoteric operation, it is not supported out of box as far as I am aware but this is a good and fast method for any reasonable size of data. Obviously pairwise operations result in large explosions of computation and memory but that's because of the inherent complexity of your algorithm, not numpy's fault.

Comment: Now I notice this doesn't take the `origin` foreign keys  from the original index. Assume the original id column could contain anything, and the very same thing should be in the new `row` `col` columns.