# How to perform a pandas operation between multiple rows while saving the origin in multiindex

Tags: python, pandas

As a followup to [my previous question on the subject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56688012/perform-an-operation-on-all-pairs-of-rows-in-a-column)

Assume the following DataFrame:

```
id    A   
1     0
2     10
3     200
4     3000
```

I would like to make a calculation betweeen all rows to all other rows.
For example, if the calculation were `lambda r1, r2: abs(r1-r2)`, then one way to form an output would be

```
id    id2    out        
1     2       10         
1     3       200         
1     4       3000       
2     1       10        
2     3       190        
2     4       2990       
3     1       200         
3     2       190        
3     4       2800        
4     1       3000      
4     2       2990       
4     3       2800
```

as far as I understand from [the doc about multi-index](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html), this can be done automatically somehow - at least the indexing part.

I am however unable to select the best way from this very long doc to get what I want.

How can I get the specified output from the input, assuming the function that calculates out could be a very complicated one, operating on multiple columns, A (simple) example would be: `lambda x,y: x['col1'] + x['col2'] // y['col3'] * y['col4']`

Comment: You commented in your original question that your `real use case is calculating all distances between a list of 3d points [given as 6 columns as input]`. What do you plan to do with these distances? If you need to find each point's nearest neighbour, or k nearest neighbours, etc., you might want to look into the k-d tree data structure, which has implementations in scikit-learn (https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KDTree.html) and scipy (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.cKDTree.html). Way faster and memory-efficient.

Comment: @PeterLeimbigler I will need to do some analysis which is not yet clear. Probably I will need to query "all distances for which their orininating points answer some predicate". I will not need knn. probably.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you need ?

```
df=df.set_index('id')
s=list(itertools.permutations(df.index, 2)) 
pd.DataFrame([x+(abs(df.A.loc[x[1]]-df.A.loc[x[0]]),) for x in s ]).set_index([0,1])
        2
0 1      
1 2    10
  3   200
  4  3000
2 1    10
  3   190
  4  2990
3 1   200
  2   190
  4  2800
4 1  3000
  2  2990
  3  2800
```

---

Or

```
s=pd.DataFrame(abs(df.A.values[:,None]-df.A.values),index=df.id,columns=df.id).astype(float)
s.values[[np.arange(len(s))]*2]=np.nan
s.stack()
id  id
1   2       10.0
    3      200.0
    4     3000.0
2   1       10.0
    3      190.0
    4     2990.0
3   1      200.0
    2      190.0
    4     2800.0
4   1     3000.0
    2     2990.0
    3     2800.0
dtype: float64
```

Comment: I guess it would be the shortest code, but I would like `0` and `1` to be part of a multi index.

Comment: @Gulzar adding a new method :-)

Comment: @WeNYoBen Always love your answers!

Answer (score 1):

We can approach this problem the following:

1. Define all the combinations with `itertools.product`.
2. Merge our values back to our combinations
3. Calculate our `out` column

```
from itertools import product

# Step 1 define all combinations
df2 = pd.DataFrame(list(product(df['id'], df['id'])), columns=['id', 'id2'])

# Step 2 merge our values back
df2 = df2.merge(df, on='id').merge(df, 
                                   left_on='id2', 
                                   right_on='id', 
                                   suffixes=['', '_2']).drop('id_2', axis=1)

# Step 3 Create our new "out" column
df = df2[df2['id'].ne(df2['id2'])]
df['out'] = abs(df2['A'] - df2['A_2'])
```

---

```
    id  id2     A   A_2   out
1    2    1    10     0    10
2    3    1   200     0   200
3    4    1  3000     0  3000
4    1    2     0    10    10
6    3    2   200    10   190
7    4    2  3000    10  2990
8    1    3     0   200   200
9    2    3    10   200   190
11   4    3  3000   200  2800
12   1    4     0  3000  3000
13   2    4    10  3000  2990
14   3    4   200  3000  2800
```

Comment: Ah oke, waiting for OP's response then @anky_91

Answer (score 1):

Set the original dataframe:

```
print(df)

   id     A
0   1     0
1   2    10
2   3   200
3   4  3000
```

#### Create a new dataframe the length of the desired frame.

```
df_count = pd.DataFrame()
for n in range(df.shape[0]):
    df_count = pd.concat([df_count, df], axis=0)
df_count = df_count.reset_index(drop=True)
df_count.index.name = 'idx'

print(df_count)

    id     A
idx          
0     1     0
1     2    10
2     3   200
3     4  3000
4     1     0
5     2    10
6     3   200
7     4  3000
8     1     0
9     2    10
10    3   200
11    4  3000
12    1     0
13    2    10
14    3   200
15    4  3000
```

#### Create a second frame and re-sort

```
df_repeat = df_count.sort_values('id').reset_index(drop=True)
df_repeat.columns = ['id_r', 'A_r']
df_repeat.index.name = 'idx'
print(df_repeat)

     id_r   A_r
idx            
0       1     0
1       1     0
2       1     0
3       1     0
4       2    10
5       2    10
6       2    10
7       2    10
8       3   200
9       3   200
10      3   200
11      3   200
12      4  3000
13      4  3000
14      4  3000
15      4  3000
```

#### join the two frames along columns,

```
df_joined = df_count.join(df_repeat, lsuffix='_1',  rsuffix='_2')

# eliminate duplicates and set the multi index.
df_joined = df_joined[df_joined['id'] != df_joined['id_r']].set_index(['id_r', 'id'], drop=True)
```

#### calculate the output.

```
df_joined['result'] = abs(df_joined['A'] - df_joined['A_r'])

            A   A_r  result
id_r id                    
1    2     10     0      10
     3    200     0     200
     4   3000     0    3000
2    1      0    10      10
     3    200    10     190
     4   3000    10    2990
3    1      0   200     200
     2     10   200     190
     4   3000   200    2800
4    1      0  3000    3000
     2     10  3000    2990
     3    200  3000    2800
```