# How to create a dataframe which has a variable length time-vector in each slot?

Tags: python, pandas

I need to create a dataframe which looks something like so:

```
ind    data                    other
1      [0.1, 7.4, 5.6,    ]    's'
2      [1.1, 4.4,         ]    'a'
3      [1.1,              ]    's'
4      [1.1, 2.4, 2.2, 8.7]    'w'
```

where items in the 'data' column are of variable length.

[To my understanding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56688012/perform-an-operation-on-all-pairs-of-rows-in-a-column), a dataframe should be 2d, and having it store lists will cause future problems for processing using pandas build in functions.

Is pandas just the wrong way to go?

How would this extend to multi dimensional arrays?

Comment: It's not optimal, but it also depends on how big your dataframe will be and what you want to do with it. Sometimes suboptimal is okay.

Comment: Well having a column with lists isn't really useful, since generally any operation on it will involve custom `apply` functions or looping over it, which will not be efficient. You're much better off using numpy arrays

Comment: @yatu Allright then, how would I do this if instead of lists there were numpy arrays of variable length?